# login from txt file in python

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

Newbie here. I need help please.

This is my text file (user.txt) and it contains:

username and password

```
admin, adm1n
user1, us3r1
user2, us3r2
user3, us3r3
```

This is the current code:

```
content = ""
user_List = []


while True:

    print("Username")
    username = input()
    print("Password")
    password = input()
    name_pass = username + " " + password + "\n"

    with open("user.txt" , "r+") as f:
        for line in f:
            if name_pass == line[:-1]:
                
                x = False
                break
            else:
                x = True

    if x == False:
        print("Welcome")
        break
    elif x == True:
        print("Incorrect Username or Password \nPlease try again")
```

My problem is when I input both the correct or incorrect password it prints out incorrect username and password.

How do I better understand the while loop so I can get my head around this please.

Comment: I'd suggest the following approach: Load your file into a dictionary, where you have user as the key and password as the value. Then when you input a user and password check if user exist in the dictionary and if so check that the value for that user matches the introduced password

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me just put out there that dealing with credentials in such a way is **not secure**. Better alternatives exist in Python check this one: https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

As for your code example, you would probably want to read the *.txt file once and then compare the input against your database.

```py
credentials = []
with open("user.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        user, pwd = line.split(sep=", ")
        # The *.strip() is important here since the line always contains the '\n' character
        credentials.append((user.strip(), pwd.strip()))

print(credentials)
while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input()
    print("Password")
    password = input()

    if (username, password) in credentials:
        print("Welcome")
        break
    print("Incorrect username or password", "Please try again", sep='\n')
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I will read into your link. Appreciate the speedy response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following approach: Load your file into a dictionary, where you have user as the key and password as the value. Then when you input a user and password check if user exist in the dictionary and if so check that the value for that user matches the introduced password

```
def loadUsers():
    usersDict = {}
    with open("user.txt" , "r+") as f:
        for line in f:
            user, passw = line.split(', ')
            usersDict[user] = passw
    return usersDict

users = loadUsers()
username = input("Username")
password = input("Password")

if username not in users:
     print(f"User not found {username}")
elif users[username] != password: 
     print(f"Incorrect password for user {username}")
else:
    print("Welcome")
```

Comment: thank you.  I receive an expected error on "pass" and "user" not defined. Appreciate your speedy response.

Comment: Did you copy my code as is? user and passw are defined